# Sending data to ASP.NET C# from android app

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

In my app I want to send some customer data from Android app to asp.net website (c#) so please help me with it .

Answer (score 3):

You need HTTP server on c# side and send data by GET or POST method or TCP server and send data by sockets. 
  It much easier to use HTTP with c# , web services. You can send or get data with

```
public HttpResponse doGet() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("url with or without parameters");
    HttpResponse respose = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    return respose;
}
```

or post

```
public HttpResponse doPost() throws IOException, JSONException, ClientProtocolException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url with or without parameters");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expose a JSON endpoint in your website. For example, if you're using MVC:

```
    public ActionResult JSONDoSomething(string param)
    {
        return Json("your result here", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then consume it on the client:

```
    String url = "http://yourhost/yourapp/JSONDoSomething?param=" + param;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);  

    BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  

    String result = "Nothing";
    try {
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). Instead of ASP.NET its PHP. Logic is the same

There are few steps to it.
**A) Android Code**

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> parms = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmpID", EmpID));

 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 InputStream is = null;

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxx/some.aspx");
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parms));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 is = entity.getContent();
```

B) ASP.NET

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RnD;Persist Security Info=True;)) //change as needed
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            string UserID = Request.Form["EmpID"];
            //SQL CODE

            string c = "sql Code";
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(c, cn);
                cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>(rdr.FieldCount);
                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        d[rdr.GetName(i)] = rdr.GetValue(i);
                    }
                    list.Add(d);
                }
                JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Response.Write("{\"JSON\":");
                Response.Write(j.Serialize(list.ToArray()));
                Response.Write("}");


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Response.Write("Error occurred. Query=" + c + "\n");
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());

            }
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```